# Why can I not move certain files to certain folders? I can only copy the files

Tags: macos, permission, big-sur, copy-paste

MacBook Air, Early 2014 running macOS Big Sur 11.7.4

I'm using an external drive (exFAT partition) hooked up via Thunderbolt and this is the first I've seen this behavior.

There are certain files I cannot move from one directory to another on the same external drive.

<s>The option for `Cut` is greyed out in the `Edit` menu.  Using `Ctrl + X` gives me an Apple error beep.</s>  (I've struck this out because it is irrelevant: `Cut` is *always* greyed out for file actions in *Finder*.)

Trying to drag the files to the intended destination folder while holding the `Command` key does nothing (the green plus sign indicating a `Copy` action is always present).

What's weird is that I can move other folders and files on the same drive with no problem.  It's only some files.

This external drive contains a mix of various pictures and videos from various memory cards from various cameras.  It seems all the files from one particular camera have this problem.

However, when I examine the permissions of the various files in *Terminal*, they all seem the same - in other words, the files that I can move with no problem and the files that I can't move seem to have the same permissions.

The permissions I see are (where `Standard.User` is my currently logged in user):

`-rwxrwxrwx Standard.User staff`

A few files have the permissions set as

`-rwxrwxrwx@ Standard.User staff`

But this small difference doesn't seem to correspond to the difference I see in copy/move behavior.

Comment: To follow-up on the discussion in the now-deleted answer: Finding the right level of detail when posting is sometimes more an art than a science. Nevertheless, based on experience from this site, it usually is better to start small and problem-/outcome-focused, avoid speculations, and add details based on things people ask for in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple enough.  There were actually only a few files that couldn't be moved within a large block that I was trying to move.  Once I narrowed down the problematic files that were causing the problems, the solution was to right-click, `Get Info` (alternatively select the file and press `command + I`), and then look for a little blue checkmark next to the option for `Locked` and *un*check it.

Done.